# Set 2 rows of a table as the last ones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a table at HTML using [dataTables](https://datatables.net/). 
The table is created dynamically via javascript and I want to set 2 specific rows as the last ones (Like Summary) no matter what. 
My problem occurs when I use table sorting , and that 2 rows are not the last ones anymore.

The solution I thought is to define these 2 rows at a new table in which I won't use sorting , but I don't know if this is the proper way to do that .

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share what did you in your code?

Comment: Of course, just tell me what exactly you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `<tfoot>` tag.